# How to show divs when the mouse moves anywhere on screen, not just the element itself?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I managed to hide and show my classes when the user moves his mouse over the specific element. But what I would actually like is that these show when the user moves his mouse anywhere on the screen, not just the selected div's.

This is my current code:

```
$(window).on('mousemove', function () {
  $('.barhide').addClass('show');
  try {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  } catch (e) {}
  timer = setTimeout(function () {
    $('.barhide').removeClass('show');
  }, 1000);
});
```

And my css:

```css
.barhide {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1.5s ease;
}

.barhide.show {
  opacity: 1;
  display: none;
}
```

So what I would like is that after 3 seconds, the classes with .barhide get hidden and if the user moves his mouse anywhere in screen, they show up again, instead of just when they move over the element.

Also I was wondering if it's not a lot easier to do these things with React?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have restructured the code a bit and added some comments explaining what's happening and when. Also, lose the `try` since attempting to clear a timer will never throw an exception.

Keep in mind that `mouseover` type events are an issue on mobile devices. These two articles may help in that regard:

[JQuery's Virtual Mouse Events](https://api.jquerymobile.com/vmouseover/)

[Simulated Mouse Events using JQuery](http://www.zyxware.com/articles/4047/how-do-you-add-an-event-mouseover-hover-on-touch-devices-using-jquery)

```js
$(function(){
  // When page loads, wait 3 seconds and hide all elements with .barhide class:
  setTimeout(toggle, 3000);
});

var timer = null;

// General function for adding/removing the "hide" class.
// This is used when the page first loads and each time
// the mouse moves on the page. We're not calling toggle()
// here because a flicker effect can happen which would leave
// the elements showing instead of being hidden.
function toggle(){
  $('.barhide').toggleClass('hide');
}

$(window).on('mousemove', function(){
  // When anywhere on page is moused over bring back .barhide
  // elements for 3 seconds. Removing "hide" simply restores
  // the original CSS & layout
  $('.barhide').removeClass('hide');
  
  // Kill any previous timers
  clearTimeout(timer);
  
  // Wait 3 seconds and hide again
  timer = setTimeout(toggle, 3000)
});
```

```css
.barhide { background-color:blue; }
.hide { display:none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="barhide">ONE</div>
<div class="show">TWO</div>
```

Comment: You've accidentally removed the `clearTimeout()` call too

Comment: If you keep moving the mouse over the element then you'll see that it keeps quickly appearing/disappearing due to the old timeout not being cleared

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yep, I was looking at a different piece of code. Not awake yet! Answer updated.

Comment: This actually doesn't work the way I want it to work. Now it still only shows the elements when I move my mouse on their surface area instead of the whole page.

Comment: @Deelux Can you be more specific? What does "shows the elements on their surface area instead of the whole page" mean?

Comment: Yes for sure, thanks for taking the time. You can check the application I am building here: http://37.139.31.151/
So if you go click, watch first episode, then next city you arrive at Shanghai, here you see the bars hide after 3 seconds, and you can show them again when you mouse over their area. 

What I would like is that where ever the user moves his mouse in the whole screen (so anywhere, on the page) it will show the bars again.

Comment: Ow this isn't working on Mobile yet btw... Just in case you are viewing the page on mobile.

Comment: Hmmm... No sadly it is still only showing the barhide elements when I actually move over their surface area and not when I just move my mouse. 
This is a tricky one.... :-S

Comment: Why the background-color : blue btw?

Comment: Btw, when I add all of your code, the bars don't hide anymore, also not after 3 seconds.

Comment: @Deelux That's not at all what's happening in the snippet above. The bars come back when moving the mouse over any area of the window. Are you saying that MY SNIPPET above isn't working for you?

Comment: 1. They are not hiding
2. I can't check if they come back when moving anywhere

I also don't understand why they don't hide

Let me check it again

Comment: Nope, they are not hiding

Comment: @Deelux I don't mean to push... But, can you clarify.... Does the snippet above work, **here on this page without you trying to copy it over to your own code**? And, are you trying this from a non-touch device? The code is very straight-forward and cross-browser compatible. If you are saying that it won't work, right here in the above SO sample, then there are other issues at hand for you.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. The example does work here, but when I copy the code to my application it doesn't work. Yet I have no idea why not.

Comment: @Deelux Ok, now we're getting somewhere. Clearly, the issue is with this code conflicting with other code in your page. Or, simply an error with your other code that is preventing this code from running. If there isn't too much, you may want to update your question here to include your complete code that you are working with.

Comment: I think it's not running in my application because the function doesn't get fired automaticly.

Comment: @Deelux Silly question, but you do have JQuery referenced by its own `script` tag prior to any of your JavaScript, right (just like in the source code of my snippet)?

Comment: At the moment I have two things which are not clear to me. 
1. Why does my code above work without a problem and why does your code snippet not work when I add it.
2. Should I still have to add jQuery when the first code snippet runs without a problem, that means the problem is not jQuery related right?

Btw, I am trying to add this in a Meteor/React application and also wonder now whether it's not better to achieve the same result with React.

Comment: And I don't add jQuery manually, if I am not mistaken it gets added automaticly by one of my packages.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have any experience with Meteor/React so I can't speak to that. But, if you have other JQuery code that does work, then JQuery has been added correctly. The issue is either that an error somewhere else in your code is preventing this new code from running or you are not integrating this code into your existing code correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You just count the nr of timers running and when the last finishes you hide the bar.

```
var count = 0;

$(window).mousemove(function( event ) {
  $('.barhide').show();
  count += 1;

  setTimeout(function() {
    if (count == 1) {
      $('.barhide').hide();
    }
    count -= 1;
  }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work, now the elements don't hide at all anymore.